# Error fetching JSON Data from Firebase Real Time Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The idea is to authenticate users first and then show the data stored on Firebase Database using REST API. However, everytime I try doing so, I keep getting 404 as the status code for reasons completely unknown to me upon debugging. Below is the entire code for fetching the Firebase Payload token and then the class from where the API call is being made with the token. I have also posted the error log.

main.dart

```
class FormApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => Auth()
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ProductItems>(
            create: (context) => ProductItems(),
            update: (context, auth, previousData) => previousData!
              ..update(auth.token, previousData == null ? {} : previousData.items)
        ),
child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (context, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "Form App",
          theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              accentColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor
          ),
          home: auth.isAuth ? FormScreen() : AuthScreen(),
```

auth.dart(The class meant for authenticating users)

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String? _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String? _userId;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String? get token {
    if(_token != null && _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) && _expiryDate != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? get userId {
    return _userId;
  }

  Future<void> authenticate(String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: json.encode({
        'email' : email,
        'password' : password,
        'returnSecureToken' : true
      }));
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData);
      if(responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      print('Token $_token');
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      print('User ID $_userId');
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
          .add(
          Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn']))
      );
      print('Expiry Date $_expiryDate');
    } catch(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    return authenticate(email, password, 'signUp?key=AIzaSyARv6bMdExBEqQzx6Wo4p8COB-CYetOdWQ');
  }

  Future<void> logIn(String email, String password) async {
    return authenticate(email, password, 'signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyARv6bMdExBEqQzx6Wo4p8COB-CYetOdWQ');
  }
}
```

products.dart(Class from which the API call is being made)

```
class Products {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;

  Products({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl
  });
}

class ProductItems with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Products> _items = {};

  String? token;

  void update(authToken, items) {
    token = authToken;
    _items = items;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Map<String, Products> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
 final url = Uri.https('form-app-c5343-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com', '/products.json?auth=$token');
 final response = await http.get(
     url,
     headers: {
       HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader : "Basic $token"
     }
 );
 print('Token: $token');
   final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
   print(json.decode(response.body));
   final Map<String, Products> map = {};
   extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
     map.putIfAbsent(key, () => Products(
         id: key,
         title: value['title'],
         description: value['description'],
         price: value['price'],
         imageUrl: value['imageUrl']
     ));
   });
   _items = map;
   print('Items $_items');
   notifyListeners();
```

}
The Error log:

```
I/flutter ( 9772): User ID rKjLKmQqM9S7BcN7dQBQBRge9W23
I/flutter ( 9772): Expiry Date 2021-08-18 01:56:30.838235
E/flutter ( 9772): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Cannot Authenticate
E/flutter ( 9772): #0      ProductItems.fetchAndSetProducts (package:form_app/provider/products.dart:79:7)
E/flutter ( 9772): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9772):
```

Although the response returns the Firebase Sign in with email/password payload, I do not seem to receive any json response for the data that I intend to fetch from Firebase's Real Time Database.
Also, the rules set in the Database are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",  // 2021-8-19
    ".write": "auth != null",  // 2021-8-19
  }
}
```

However, prior to authenticating users, the call was working without any issues at all with the response as well which looked something like this:

```
    {
    "products" : {
        "-MfbcM0c0b-dix_KGok1" : {
          "description" : "A red shirt - it is pretty red!",
          "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg",
          "price" : 29.99,
          "title" : "Red Shirt"
        },

}
```

Comment: Can Someone tell me if I'm even parsing the data properly?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lay in the way I was defining the URL. The parameter format for the `Uri.https` constructor should be

```
Uri.https(String authority, String unencodedPath, [Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters]).
```

So therefore, I should have defined my URL as per the format which should look something like this:

```
final url = Uri.https('form-app-c5343-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com', '/products.json', {'auth' : '$token'});
```

Comment: brothes its working oh my god!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add authorization in headers.
see this link https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests